# c# generic enum as constructor argument

Tags: c#, enums, parameters

So:

Project B references Project A, Project A is a core library

Project A has an attribute class with a constructor that currently accepts an array of strings (inProjectPermissionTypes):

```
public class Read : Attribute
{
    
   public string[] ProjectPermissionTypes;
   public enumPermissionType PermissionType;
    
   public Read(enumPermissionType inPermissionType, params string[] inProjectPermissionTypes)
   {
      this.ProjectPermissionTypes = inProjectPermissionTypes;
      this.PermissionType = inPermissionType;
   }
    
}
```

Project B uses the above class as an attribute

```
[Attributes.Permissions.Project.Read(Attributes.Permissions.enumPermissionType.ALLOW, "P1", "P2")]
```

I'd like to replace the  "P1", "P2" part with an array of enum values from an emum that lives in Project B - problem is - how to do this - as Project A can have no direct knowledge of the enum in Project B, I cant put the enum in Project A, so im thinking there's maybe a generic way to set:

```
params string[] inProjectPermissionType
```

so something like:

```
params magicEnum inProjectPermissionType
```

that will accept any enum which i can take apart in the constructor?

ive sen some questions that make this sound impossible - its the friendly nature of the enum shielding the integer value that im after, so any ideas around this would also be appreciated.

many thanks

Comment: foreach(string p in inProjectPermissionTypes)
{
   PermissionType = (enumPermissionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(enumPermissionType), p);
}

Comment: *"as Project A can have no direct knowledge of the enum in Project A"* - typo? You mean enum in project B?

Comment: Yup thanks - typo fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In project B Add a Attribute class that inherits project A's Read Attribute, lets call it `ProjectBRead`. Then use that Attribute in project B

```
enum YourEnum
{
    P1,
    P2
}


public class ProjectBRead : Read // Read from project A
{    
   public ProjectBRead(enumPermissionType inPermissionType, params YourEnum[] inProjectPermissionTypes)
   : base(inPermissionType, inProjectPermissionTypes.Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray())
   {
     
   }
    
}
```

Then use like this in Project B:

`[ProjectBRead(Attributes.Permissions.enumPermissionType.ALLOW,YourEnum.P1, YourEnum.P2)]`

Comment: This is fantastic thanks, primarily because i understand it but overlooked it as a solution, its slightly unfortunate having to implement the code in Project B (consider all the types of permissions - Read, Edit, Archive etc) but it does lean on the Constructor in Project B and allows me to use the enum which was the whole point, so I thank you again

Comment: @glumlun if it is a solution you can use, please mark as answer

Comment: Just to note 2 issues with the syntax : base not : Base and .ToArray() not .ToArray

Answer (score 0):

Would be of great help to contextualize where do you use this attribute (check link at the end).

From what you provided, you could declare a generic interface in your A project, and then declare a concrete type on your B project.

```
public interface IRead<TPermissionType> where TPermissionType : Enum
{
    public TPermissionType[] Permissions { get; }
}

public enum MyEnum { }

public class ReadConcrete : Attribute, IRead<MyEnum>
{
    public MyEnum[] Permissions { get; }

    public ReadConcrete(MyEnum[] permissions)
    {
        Permissions = permissions;
    }
}
```

*https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example*

Comment: This is interesting, thanks, I use the attribute on a class in Project B, and consume information on that class from Project A using reflection. I've tried implementing what you suggest but cannot see how it leads to being able to use the enum form Project B in the constructor for the attributes class

Comment: Please provide the code where you consume the attribute, so your question is fully reproducible.